# How to prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+k} {9/2 \choose k}=\frac{2}{11}~(32\sqrt{2}-1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How to prove that $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+k} {9/2 \choose k}=\frac{2}{11}~(32\sqrt{2}-1).$$ I have no idea of handling binomial coefficient when the upper index is non-integer. Please help.

Comment: Try to integrate both sides of the [Binomial Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(1+t)^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{x \choose k} t^k, 0<t \le 1, x>0$$
Integrating.w.r.t.$t$ from $t=0$ to $t=1$ both sides, we get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{{x\choose k}}{k+1}=\frac{2^{x+1}-1}{x+1}$$
Put $x=9/2$, to get the required result.

Comment: @Z Ahmed Thank you very much. What I had $9.3$ in place of $9/2$?

Comment: Welcome ! then put $x=9.3$